# Binding multiple css classes with a <li> Element using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I have a `<li>` element with knockout `css` binding like this:

```
<li data-bind="css: itemSelectionClass" >
```

The value of the `itemSelectionClass` is set dynamically to either of 'active' or 'empty' (means inactive). The of `itemSelectionClass` come from some computable function. After the binding is done, when I inspect the element from the browser I get:

```
<li data-bind="css: itemSelectionClass" class="active">
```

I just want to add another `css` class - `readDone`. I am expecting something like this after the binding has done:

```
<li data-bind="css: itemSelectionClass" class="active readDone">
```

But it's not working as expected. Can anyone help? My main purpose is to bind the `<li>` element with 2 css classes dynamically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How exactly `itemSelectionClass` is described? Do you want to bind two classes at the same time, or should `readDone` be always applied to that element?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. No `readDone` doesn't always apply the element and I wan't to bind the two classes at the same time.

Comment: binding to two classes per the documentation is as easy as doing `'classA ClassB' : someVar` per  my downvoted answer below

Comment: Did my answer help/fix the issue?

Comment: @gh9, sorry it didn't. But thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle, and I will take a look at it

Comment: This is a simple task and the answer posted by gh9, or the knockout documentation itself, provides clear examples. If it's not working for you then something else is causing an error. Please edit your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <div data-bind="css: { profitWarning: currentProfit() < 0, majorHighlight: isSevere }">
```

You can set multiple CSS classes at once. For example, if your view model has a property called isSevere,

```
<div data-bind="css: { profitWarning: currentProfit() < 0, 'major highlight': isSevere }">
```

[Knockout Documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html)